# How do I prevent the query class from processing the question marks in my text strings?

Tags: php, sql, phpquery

Rather new to php, so sorry if this seems stupid. I'm really copying a lot of this from previously written code from other developers at my company.

The way we run a query is basically like this:

```
$qry = new SQLQuery;
$sqlString = "SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE table.text = '" . 
              $textVar . "' and table.text2 = '" . $text2Var."'";
$qry->prepare(String::Condense($sqlString));
$qry->execute();
```

The problem I'm having is that `$textVar` or `$text2Var` may legitimately have question marks (?) in them as part of their text, this is causing the query SQLQuery class to break treating the question mark as a variable I'm not passing it.

So how can I instruct the SQLQuery class to ignore question marks?

p.s. I'm sure there's terminology for a lot of this that I don't know, please keep that in mind when giving me an answer.

Comment: what SQLQuery class are you using? It's not a built in.

Comment: @Kris - I have no idea, I never used php prior to this job and I'm just duplicating code I see elsewhere in the product. I had no idea SQLQuery wasn't part of the main php library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your prepared statement `$sqlString` to have `?` where you are putting `$textVar` and `$text2var`, and then you need to bind those to the statement.

It's treating them as placeholders because *they look like placeholders* when you prepare your SQL.

So:

```
$sqlString = "SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE table.text = ? and table.text2 = ?"
```

You should take a look at [**MySQL Prepared Statements**](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) and familiarize yourself with how they work and what benefits they provide.

Comment: So lets say I switch it to look like 
`WHERE table.text = '?' and table.text2 = '?'";` and then I feed it the variables, even if the variables have `?` as part of their text it will be OK? Do I have to prepare if my `$sqlString` is ready to go? if so how do I execute the query without preparing?

Comment: @invertedSpear: I don't know what DB wrapper you are using so it is hard to answer. You **want** to use prepared queries, though, so you don't have to worry about sanitizing everything. And yes, your values will be able to have ?s in them, no problem.

Comment: Wish I knew more about php so I could ask a better question. I'll switch it all over to prepared/parametered statements. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It kinda looks like some PDO derivative so it should probably be something more like:

```
$qry = new SQLQuery;
$sqlString = 'SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE table.text=? AND table.text2=?'
$qry->prepare($sqlString);
$qry->execute(array($textVar, $text2Var));
```